# How to use ID in Query in BookshelfJS?

Tags: node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have one field & it has **comma separated** ID, so i want to find from that selected id, here is my code,

```
.get(function(req, res) {
  knex.select('*')
  .from('exam')
  .whereRaw('? = any(regexp_split_to_array(student_id))', [req.params.id])
  .then(function(rows) {
    //return res.send(rows);
    console.log(rows);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  });
});
```

===> while i am using **KNEX** it will give an Error Like this,

```
{ error: function regexp_split_to_array(text) does not exist
  name: 'error',
  length: 220,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42883',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: 'No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.',
  position: '37',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_func.c',
  line: '523',
  routine: 'ParseFuncOrColumn' 
}
```

1. in **student_id** column i have ID like this, **33,34,35,36**
2. in **req.params.id** i got only one single ID like, 35.
3. so i want that **rows** which have included 35 ID, in Same Table.

[image]

===> **So i want Only Two Rows (2,3) because it has Included ID = 35.**

Comment: Knex only creates SQL query and send it to SQL. The SQL on its own cannot search in "comma separated" strings natively. You can search for student_id LIKE '%35%', but it will be expensive operation (if you have lot of rows) and it will also find ID with 35 included like 135. Maybe you can use some special SQL commands that can do something with commas.

Comment: @libik yes, with the use of LIKE if any other column have 354 ID then it will fetch that ROW also, but i need only rows which have 35 ID.

Comment: So maybe something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns

Comment: If you're storing multiple ids in the same column you're using the wrong relation type. You should probably be using `belongsToMany` instead.

Comment: @devius it's not about Relation, i want data from SAME table, not from reference table.

Comment: @devius i want only that rows which have included 'student_id' = 35 from SAME table.

Comment: It is about relation because you want to get the exams that belong to a student with a certain id. That could easily be achieved with a `belongsToMany` relation where an Exam [belongsToMany](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-belongsToMany) Student, which would create a join table between the two models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using PostgreSQL database (I saw you use phpPgAdmin on the screenshot). You can use [regexp_split_to_array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) function to convert your string to array (obviously :). And the perform search over the resulting array using any.

In SQL words, it can be written like this

```
select '35' = any(regexp_split_to_array('33,34,35,36', E','));
```

In your query, you can replace `.where` with

```
.whereRaw("? = any(regexp_split_to_array(student_id, E','))", [req.params.id])
```

But keep in mind, this can be performance-heavy request, as for each row you execute string split operation. A better way of doing this (assuming it is necessary for your project to contain array values in one row) is to store your `student_id` in the Array type and add [gin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-indexes.html) index on `student_id` column and perform search operations like [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html)

```
select * from table where student_id @> '{35}';
```

Comment: i get this ERROR 'Exam.whereRaw is not a function', actually i am using BookshelfJS, so how can i use this Query in BookshelfJS?

Comment: @Chaudhary ok, try this one `.where(bookshelf.knex.raw('? = any(regexp_split_to_array(student_id))', [req.params.id]))`
I'm actually not familliar with bookshelfjs, but using `knex` tools it should be working.

Comment: i update my question, while i am using KNEX it will give an Error.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed second parameter for `regexp_split_to_array` in `knex` representation, `, E','`. I'll update my response

Comment: coockoo ===> thanxxxx now it's working fine, thanxx.